# How can we make an Item in socialengine?

Tags: socialengine

I know how to get an item of the particular table. Like for user we can have

```
$userItem = Engine_Api::_()->getItem("user", $userId);
```

or for a custom table

```
$customItem = Engine_Api::_()->getItem("custom", $customeId);
```

I want to know the code or method how can I make my $customItem to work the same way as $userItem works for users table. So that I can get data or manipulate the data of custom table

Thanks for your help. :-)

Comment: please describe more explicitly-))

Comment: Well I have a table name let say engine4_mymodule_mytable. I want to access its row or instance just like we can do with engine4_users by calling it's item just like i mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by creating a model. Check how it's done in `/application/modules/User/Model`. There is `User.php` file that declares `User_Model_User` and methods available for User such as getTitle, get Href etc.

You may use similar approach for your custom item. You will also need to create a file similar to `/application/modules/User/Model/DbTable/User.php` to declare table for your custom items.